# How to permanently delete kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

Hi running this command kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost --delete --topic MyTopic

This works.

```
[2016-06-28 14:22:43,533] INFO Deleting index /data1/kafka/MyTopic-XX/00000000000000000000.index (kafka.log.OffsetIndex)
[2016-06-28 14:22:43,533] INFO Deleted log for partition [MyTopic,xx] in /data1/kafka/MyTopic-xx. (kafka.log.LogManager)
```

Where XX is the partition. When I go look at the kafka log dir the topic is deleted, but then after a few minutes it reappears.

When I look at kafka logs I see...

```
 INFO Created log for partition [MyTopic,XX] in /data1/kafka with properties {compression.type -> producer, message.format.version -> 0.10.0-IV1, file.delete.delay.ms -> 60000, max.message.bytes -> 1000012, message.timestamp.type -> CreateTime, min.insync.replicas -> 1, segment.jitter.ms -> 0, preallocate -> false, min.cleanable.dirty.ratio -> 0.5, index.interval.bytes -> 4096, unclean.leader.election.enable -> true, retention.bytes -> -1, delete.retention.ms -> 86400000, cleanup.policy -> delete, flush.ms -> 9223372036854775807, segment.ms -> 604800000, segment.bytes -> 1073741824, retention.ms -> 604800000, message.timestamp.difference.max.ms -> 9223372036854775807, segment.index.bytes -> 10485760, flush.messages -> 9223372036854775807}. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2016-06-28 13:59:39,623] INFO Partition [MyTopic,XX] on broker 0: No checkpointed highwatermark is found for partition [MyTopic,XX] (kafka.cluster.Partition)
```

So it seems to be re-creating it somehow?

Thanks

Comment: Topic deletion option is disabled by default. To enable it set the server config delete.topic.enable=true and restart the kafka. Then use the following command: bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zk_host:port/chroot --delete --topic my_topic_name

Comment: I do have it enable otherwise why would it physically delete the folders and then recreate it?

Comment: Also I ran the exact same command as you stated the only difference I see from yours and mine is the chroot.

Comment: Ok I rebooted the server and all topics are gone. I was trying with the above commands and also manually deleting the topics but they kept coming back. I probably had a rogue zookeeper running in screen that I forgot about lol

Comment: Err nope it's still doing it though rebooting did stop it from doing what it's doing. So even if I stopp both zookeeper and kafka and then physically delete the files the topics keep comming back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable `auto.create.topics.enable` property in the broker.

**CAUTION**: This property is enabled by default. Requests from a producer / consumer to a topic which don't exists gets created automatically. If you going to disable it, make sure that you're creating the required topics before starting your client applications.

Comment: And where would I find the `auto.create.topics.enable` property? There are a lot of config files and I don't see that property in any of them.