# How to delete kafka topics permanently and prevent topic recreation?

Tags: apache-kafka

Reference [How to permanently delete kafka topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38083649/how-to-permanently-delete-kafka-topic)

How to achieve the following scenario : i) auto.create.topics.enable=true for new topic creation by producer . ii) stop recreation of a topic after deleting that topic .

N.B. I had delete.topic.enable value false by default while creating that topic .

Answer (score 0):

To delete kafka topic ,set property `delete.topic.enable=true`

Once deleted, any new message posted to the topic will re-create again if you have set `auto.create.topics.enable=true`

And if you have set the property `auto.create.topics.enable=false` then you have to create the topic manually before posting the data to topic.